# How to aim a package.json file in dockerfile if the dockerfile is inside another folder in the root directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Currently the structure of the directory is

```
root/
  package.json
  app.js
docker/
  backend.Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yaml
```

and when i try to run the docker compose it keeps failing and says

```
> [4/4] RUN npm install:
#8 0.564 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#8 0.565 npm ERR! syscall open
#8 0.565 npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
#8 0.565 npm ERR! errno -2
#8 0.566 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
#8 0.566 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#8 0.566 npm ERR! enoent 
#8 0.567 
#8 0.567 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#8 0.567 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-27T09_15_42_645Z-debug-0.log
```

i understand the error means it couldnt find the package.json but on my dockerfile i already assign to copy the right directory here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app

COPY ../ .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

and here is my docker compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../:/app:cached
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Im not sure on where i did wrong but im pretty sure its my path's problem can anyone help me

So what i have try is that changing the path on the COPY command in the docker file but it seems to not work but if i move my dockerfile to the root directory it work coz my cmd in the dockerfile was

```
COPY . .
```

but when i move it into a folder inside the root directory so the structure would be root/docker/dockerfile

i decided to change the COPY command into COPY ../ ./ but it doesnt work and i got that error called

```
> [4/4] RUN npm install:
#8 0.564 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#8 0.565 npm ERR! syscall open
#8 0.565 npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
#8 0.565 npm ERR! errno -2
#8 0.566 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
#8 0.566 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#8 0.566 npm ERR! enoent 
#8 0.567 
#8 0.567 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#8 0.567 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-27T09_15_42_645Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: I have found the problem that docker doesnt allow it it should be in a up dir

Answer (score 0):

try copying what you have in the root directory

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY root/. .
RUN npm install
```

Comment: root not found i try to replace the root to my folder name of the root directory but not found

Comment: yeah makes sense cause you are in the /docker directory would you try running ```cd..``` and then use  ```COPY . .``` this way you go back to the previous directory and copy everything ik its not the perfect solution but it might work